# Is using `UIDocumentMenuViewController` without iCloud? Is there an equivalent for use with third-party apps only?

Tags: ios, uikit, icloud

Initiating a `UIDocumentMenuViewController` causes a crash without the iCloud entitlement. However, the iCloud entitlement currently blocks App Transfer: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

...So, it's unwise to enable the iCloud entitlement (or Passbook) unless absolutely necessary, as it prevents you unnecessarily from transferring the app between iTunes accounts if needed.

**My question is:** Is there any equivalent functionality (graphically) to present similar looking menus, and/or is there any way to utilize this menu or something else to similarly load from any non-iCloud document source (ie. Dropbox) without these crashes?

I've filed a radar, because this seems pretty ridiculous.